# Sum values according to specific condition in R

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

i have a df structured like this:

```
 Ateco. Numb. Reg

   10    223   A
   11    332   A
   12    343   A
   10    223   B
   11    332   B
   12    343   B
   29    414   B
   30    434   B
   31    444   B
   32    464   B
```

and I want to obtain another df, where numb is the sum of the Ateco values that I select.

```
 Ateco.     Numb.  Reg

10_11_12    898     A
10_11_12    898     B      
   29       414     B
   30       434     B
   31       444     B
   32       464     B
```

how could I do?

Comment: Try `aggregate(Ateco. ~ ., df, FUN = paste, collapse="_")` or using `dplyr` `df %>% group_by(Numb., Reg) %>% summarie(Ateco. = paste(Ateco., collapse="_"))` or `data.table` `setDT(df)[, .(Ateco. = paste(Ateco., collapse="_")), by = .(Numb., Reg)]`

Comment: yes but I have to declare which are the Ateco values that I want to aggregate

Comment: In your example, 10, 11, 12 are the only values, so it should automatically get pasted

Comment: you're right. I made some changes

Comment: Is there any other condition that specifies 10:12 in one group or not?

Comment: It is not clear to me which way you need to group the 'Ateco.' values.  Is there any logical conditon?  IN other words, how do you decide that 10:12 would b in a group

Comment: No, it is completely subjective. Because I need to aggregate that variables only, but there is no logical condition. Only my necessity

Comment: Let me know if you have any more updates with the data

Comment: Of course. I’m sorry but I have to leave. I answer you tomorrow morning. Thank you very much for you suggestions and availability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated input example, grouped by 'Reg' and the presence of values 10 to 12 in 'Ateco.', get the `sum` of 'Numb.' and `paste` the 'Ateco', elements, `ungroup` and remove the 'grp' if needed

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(Reg, grp = Ateco. %in%  10:12) %>% 
   summarise(Numb. = sum(Numb.), 
            Ateco. = paste(Ateco., collapse="_")) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Reg   Numb. Ateco.  
#  <chr> <int> <chr>   
#1 A       898 10_11_12
#2 B       414 29      
#3 B       898 10_11_12
```

---

If we assume the 'grp' is created based on the occurence of 'Ateco' values in both the 'Reg' elements

```
df %>% 
    group_by(Ateco.) %>%
    group_by(grp = n_distinct(Reg) > 1, Reg) %>% 
    summarise(Numb. = sum(Numb.),
             Ateco. = paste(Ateco., collapse="_")) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```

#### Update

Based on the new dataset

```
df2 %>% 
    group_by(Ateco. = case_when(Ateco. %in% 10:12 ~ '10_11_12', 
                   TRUE ~ as.character(Ateco.)), Reg) %>% 
    summarise(Numb. = sum(Numb.))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Ateco. [?]
#  Ateco.   Reg   Numb.
#  <chr>    <chr> <int>
#1 10_11_12 A       898
#2 10_11_12 B       898
#3 29       B       414
#4 30       B       434
#5 31       B       444
#6 32       B       464
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Ateco. = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 29L), 
Numb. = c(223L, 332L, 343L, 223L, 332L, 343L, 414L), Reg = c("A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -7L))

df2 <- structure(list(Ateco. = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 29L, 
 30L, 31L, 32L), Numb. = c(223L, 332L, 343L, 223L, 332L, 343L, 
 414L, 434L, 444L, 464L), Reg = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
 "B", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L))
```

Comment: It gives me problems if there are multiple values different from 10, 11, 12. I update the input df

Comment: It aggregates the values that I want to aggregate, but also all the others.

Comment: @Silvia  Updated the post